# SAP b1 Query date input not working with join

Tags: sql, sapb1

I am trying to pull invoice data from 2 tables OINV and INV1. I need the query to give me results for a specified date range. Here is my query:

```
SELECT T0."DocDate", T0."NumAtCard", T0."CardName", T1."ItemCode", T1."Quantity", T1."Price", T0."DocTotal" 
FROM "OINV"  T0 LEFT JOIN
     INV1 T1
     ON T0."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry" 
WHERE T0."CANCELED"  = 'N',  T0."DocDate" >=[%0] AND  T0."DocDate" <=[%1]
```

This doesn't ask for the date input when I execute it and doesn't return anything. The date input works fine when I use the OINV table alone, but doesn't when I do the join. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Commas don't belong in the `WHERE` clause.  Use `AND`.  I consider this a simple typographical error and vote to close.

Comment: Oh sorry, that was an oversight. I tried it again with the AND and it still does the same.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is correct. The query works fine if you use _WHERE T0."CANCELED"  = 'N' **AND** T0."DocDate" >=_ ...

Answer (score 1):

Add this before your code

```
 /*SELECT * FROM OINV T0*/
declare @FromDate date
declare @ToDate date
/* WHERE */
set @FromDate = /* T0.DocDate */‘[%0]’
set @ToDate =/* T0.DocDate */ ‘[%1]’
```

Answer (score 0):

the query :

```
SELECT T0."DocDate", T0."NumAtCard", T0."CardName", T1."ItemCode", T1."Quantity", T1."Price", T0."DocTotal" 
FROM "OINV"  T0 LEFT JOIN
     INV1 T1
     ON T0."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry" 
WHERE T0."CANCELED"  = 'N' AND  T0."DocDate" >=[%0] AND  T0."DocDate" <=[%1]
```

Works Fine on my System

remove the `","` and add `"AND"`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "" in all your columns.

```
SELECT T0.DocDate, T0.NumAtCard, T0.CardName, T1.ItemCode, T1.Quantity, T1.Price, T0.DocTotal
FROM OINV  T0 LEFT JOIN
     INV1 T1
     ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 
WHERE T0.CANCELED  = 'N' AND  T0.DocDate >=[%0] AND  T0.DocDate <=[%1]
```